# Android: Data storage possibilities

Tags: java, android, json, storage

I was searching through internet but I didn't get complete answer, so i'm asking here. What ways can we use to store data in the internet and get it to Android application? I know about JSON, XML Parsing or frameworks like Parse.com etc. but are there any other ways?

Thanks in advance, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Every way you can imagine. You have raw sockets to your disposal you could write your data as Word files onto a virtually mounted NAS disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see which option is best since the requirement is not clear.

For instance, how big is the data you want to access? How frequently?

If you just want to make it works now. An easy way I know is to integrate with AmazonS3 server who also provides a lib for client to integration.

You don't need know the detail of the transition, just put the path.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

By the way, for personal user, it's free.